# Parse XML Document to obtain c# code

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have got a XML document, which contains some c# code in one of its child nodes.
c# code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) { }
```

Now this c# code is causing a XML parse error due to the '=' character. I could replace it for a xml special character (&#..), but then my c# code would not run properly anymore when debugged with my eval function (Takes a string and execute it on the flow). How can i allow c# code in my xml file without causing xml parse errors, while still being able to parse a properly working c# code?

PS. I am not a XML expert so I this question might be easy if the problem has to do with xml.

Comment: Have you looked at wrapping the code as a CDATA section as mentioned here - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: To be a valid XML document, you need to encode certain characters, like `<` into `&lt;` (or put the whole thing into a `<[!CDATA[]]>` tag). Your XML library will usually handle this for you. Are you building this xml via string concatenation?

Comment: Do you have control of the xml? The code should be within a <![CDATA[ ... ]]

Comment: How are you parsing the XML? If you're using LINQ to XML, or XmlDocument then they will decode any special characters in the C# for you. And if these had been used to _create_ the XML, then the special characters would have been added automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

> I could replace it for a xml special character (&#..), but then my c# code would not run properly anymore

Then I think you've misunderstood encoding.  Assuming you don't enclose in `<!CDATA[ ]]>`, then yes, you should encode characters such as < to > when inserting text (or code in your case).  However, that doesn't mean that when you "parse" the content back, you will see an &gt; sign.  When you write data to an xml node, it gets encoded.  When you "parse" it back, the content is decoded again and you get your original text back.

This assumes you are using a standard xml parser which I would strongly advise.

Comment: Thanks, I think I 'll go with the <!CDATA[ ]]> enclosure, simply because in that case I will preserve my c# syntax. But thanks anyway for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

In XML, there are ways to escape special characters that would otherwise break the document (like < and =).

In this case your best option is to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <code>
    <![CDATA[
      for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) { }
    ]]>
  </code>
</root>
```

You can put anything inside the <![CDATA[ ... ]]> block (except ]]>), and it won't break the XML document.

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but figured I would need to strip off the <![CDATA[ ]]> manually. Although I now come to understanding that this is easily done with XmlNodeType.CDATA case. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a CDATA section or encode the characters. It doesn't matter because C# has classes to parse the XML either way and give you the decoded string to work with.

This is a rough sample of how you can generate a CDATA section in an XmlDocument in C#:

```
var xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<xml></xml>");
var xmlCDataSection = xmlDocument.CreateCDataSection("for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) { }");
var root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
root.AppendChild(xmlCDataSection);
xmlDocument.Save("d:\\example.xml");
```

Result

```
<xml><![CDATA[for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) { }]]></xml>
```

If the XML doesn't need to be human-readable then it is probably fine to not use a CDATA section in which case the XmlDoucment will encode the characters, and decode them when you read the XML back in.

I.e.

```
var xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
var xmlElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement("xml");
xmlElement.InnerText = "for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) { }";
xmlDocument.AppendChild(xmlElement);
xmlDocument.Save("d:\\example.xml");
```

Result

```
<xml>for (int i = 0; i &lt;= 20; i++) { }</xml>
```